# Refering to the same footnote - \footnotemark + \footnotemark[\value{footnote}] + \footnotetext (without \ref)

Tags: footnotes

I'd like to refer to the same footnote (possibly avoiding \ref) in the following manner:

First note

First note

Second note

First note

I tried to do this, but in the last row (above) I got Second note instead of First note:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}


First note here \footnotemark, First note here \footnotemark[\value{footnote}].
Second note here\footnote{Nota normale} First note here \footnotemark[\value{footnote}].


\footnotetext{Questa è una nota utilizzata più volte.}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter `footnote` is increased by the commands `\footnotemark` and `\footnote` in your example - which means that after the `\footnote` its value is 2 and thus the second `\footnotemark` will refer to the second footnote.

To be able to refer to a previous footnote, you could introduce an auxiliary counter, which you set at the moment you define the footnote which you want to refer to later - then you can use this counter in the last `\footnotemark` command.

Thus, your example would become:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcounter{auxFootnote}
\begin{document}

First note here \footnotemark\setcounter{auxFootnote}{\value{footnote}}, First note here \footnotemark[\value{footnote}].
Second note here\footnote{Nota normale} First note here \footnotemark[\value{auxFootnote}].

\footnotetext{Questa è una nota utilizzata più volte.}

\end{document}
```

and produces the desired output:
[image]

**Note** however, that in the actual list of footnotes, the numbering is wrong (because `\footnotetext` uses the current value of the footnote counter). The numbering can be fixed by using `\footnotetext[\value{auxFootnote}]{...}`, however that still leaves them in the wrong order - place the `\footnotetext` command before the `\footnote` for the second command to fix that. Or, indeed, simply use `\footnote` directly for the first footnote as well, like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newcounter{auxFootnote}
\begin{document}

First note here \footnote{Questa è una nota utilizzata più volte.}\setcounter{auxFootnote}{\value{footnote}}, First note here \footnotemark[\value{footnote}].
Second note here\footnote{Nota normale} First note here \footnotemark[\value{auxFootnote}].

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent solution @greyshade!